# Magento 2 - Remove cache block

Tags: magento2, blocks, cache

I've got in a custom module created on `module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` with:

```
<block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="sample:module::sampletemplate.phtml" name="sampleblock" cacheable="false" _isScopePrivate="true"/>
```

I think that if i put the `cacheable="false"` to dont let the block to be cached, but it's not working.

How could i could remove cache of this block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In block class set `_isScopePrivate` property to true on __construct() function.

So add this to your class

```
public function __construct(){
$this->_isScopePrivate = true;
}
```

Comment: Check this if you want to use  _isScopePrivate http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html, _isScopePrivate is obsolete

Comment: ..and that link is obsolete too.

Comment: _isScopePrivate is already obsolete as per the Magento 2 documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html?itm_source=devdocs&itm_medium=search_page&itm_campaign=federated_search&itm_term=isScopePrivate

Comment: @phagento Any idea how to fix that? How can i use private content?